# Problems creating a mozaic with a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

So, I'm trying to do this image processing exercise. I have to separate a 512px image in 16 equal size block, mixing them up in a pre arranged configuration, creating a **mozaic**. For this I'm using the **numpy** library and running some **tests** to see how it works. That said, I have this code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = misc.imread("test.png")

list = [(img[0:128, 0:128]), (img[0:128, 128:256]), (img[0:128, 256:384]), (img[0:128, 384:512]),
        (img[128:256, 0:128]), (img[128:256, 128:256]), (img[128:256, 256:384]), (img[128:256, 384:256]),
        (img[256:384, 0:128]), (img[256:384, 128:256]), (img[256:384, 256:384]), (img[256:384, 384:512]),
        (img[384:512, 0:128]), (img[384:512, 128:256]), (img[384:512, 256:384]), (img[384:512, 384:512])]

list[0] = list[1]
print list[0], '\n\n\n', list[1]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

As you can see, I separated the image with the index and put it all in the list. Then I'm trying to replace one "block" for other with this:

```
list[0] = list[1]
```

The problem is when I print them

```
print list[0], '\n\n\n', list[1]
```

they'are equal, but if I do

```
print img[0:128, 0:128],'\n\n', img[0:128, 128:256]
```

I can see that the real array wasn't changed at all. **How can I make the canges apply to the image array and not just to the list?** Or there is a simple way to do this? I took a look in the split functions of numpy and none of them seemed to help here.

PS: I know this works, but I **need to do with the list.**

```
img[0:128, 0:128] = list[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a list of `views` of `img` (the () are not needed)

```
alist = [img[0:128, 0:128], img[0:128, 128:256], img[0:128, 256:384], ...]
```

Doing

```
alist[0] = alist[1]
```

amounts to changing the list to:

```
alist = [img[0:128, 128:256], img[0:128, 128:256], img[0:128, 256:384], ...]
```

because the action just changes the pointer in `alist[0]` to the pointer in `alist[1]`.  Now the first 2 elements are same thing.

```
alist[0][...] = alist[1]
```

would change the contents of `alist[0]` array without changing the object that it points to.  In other words `img[0:128, 128:256]` is a mutable object, and `img[0:128, 128:256][...]=...` changes the contents (if done correctly).

This kind of action is a little tricky.  You have to match dimensions.  I first wrote `alist[0][:] = alist[1]` and then realized the `alist[0]` is a 2d array, so I need to use `[:,:]` or `[...]`.

---

Illustrating on a smaller array

```
In [69]: img=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
In [70]: alist=[img[0:2,0:2],img[0:2,2:4],img[2:4,0:2],img[2:4,2:4]]
In [71]: alist[0][...]=alist[1]
In [72]: alist
Out[72]: 
[array([[2, 3],
        [6, 7]]), array([[2, 3],
        [6, 7]]), array([[ 8,  9],
        [12, 13]]), array([[10, 11],
        [14, 15]])]
In [73]: img
Out[73]: 
array([[ 2,  3,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the [...] did the job!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on exactly what you're asking - can you just set

```
img[0:128, 0:128] = img[128:256, 128:256]
```

or are you looking for something else?

Also, be careful calling your list `list` in Python - `list` is a built-in type in Python and changing it might make things confusing later on down the track.

Comment: I was trying to get the result that

img[0:128, 0:128] = img[128:256, 128:256]

gives, but using the arrays inside the list.